# Add errors to ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if it is possible to automatically add errors to the ModelState, in order to check my else condition?

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   //Do something
}
else
{
   //Manage errors
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name is mandatory");
```