# c# Reflect the ModelState which ony has get method in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, reflection

I want to change the property Controller.ModelState.IsValid manually for testing.

During reflection, I found that the definition of ModelState and ModelStae.IsValid is just `{get;}`. So when I use PropertyInfo to reflect it , the SetMethod is null.

Then I tried to get backfield of it via GetRunningField, but what I found is 3 object: one "`_innerdictionary`", and two "`XXX<>_backfieldMethod`".That's not the same to the normal reflection for readonly property, there's no "`<propertyname>K_backfield`" in it.

Is anyone who can help? I just want to make my test work easier.

Comment: What is it that your wanting to test? (`ModelState` is set during the model binding process). You cannot set it.

Comment: You can not change the IsValid property directly coz it actually depends on if model has any error. You can add error to the model by using `ModelState.AddModelError`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046360/add-errors-to-modelstate?rq=1 when there is any error in ModelState its IsValid property will becomes false.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  For the code coverage in post method. I think it's difficult to emulate the situation for all kinds of user input to test all branch of post methods or validation attributes. But as code coverage is requested by Boss, I want to do it in tricky way, and Chetan give me the answer , thank you all the same

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  Thank you very much ~!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. What is it your trying to test? How do you think it could _make my test work easier_? (and if you think it could, then you not testing the right things)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually, I don't want to test the "right" things, as you know, for mstest/unit test/moq or other VS extension , all of them are just "unit test", there's no one will allow you to do fully "unit test" without conducting joint test /function test. So I just want to make a fake "unit test"